# Vim Search and Replace - Regex

Tags: vim, regular-expression, search, replace

I want to perform a search and replace. A newline before any non-digit should be replaced with tab. I tried

```
%s/\n\D/\t/g
```

but it replaced the first character of the word following the newline, which is not what I wanted, i.e.

```
abcd
abcd
```

to

```
abcd   bcd
```

I want to preserve `a` after the newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but your regular expression is replacing both the newline *and* the non-digit with a tab.

How about replacing every newline followed by a non-digit with a tab *and that same non-digit*?

```
%s/\n\(\D\)/\t\1/g
```

The escaping is a bit messy, but basically you have a grouping around the `\D` that will capture whatever the non-digit is. This is then referred to with `\1` to insert it after the tab.

Comment: If you have further groups in your search pattern, these are accessible through `\2`, `\3` etc.  This is not limited to `s/.../.../` in Vim but usually works like this in most tool using `s/.../.../` (most notably `sed`).

Comment: use the very magic option `\v` to deal with too many escapes `%s/\v\n(\D)/\t\1/g`

Comment: @spasic That's a Vim thing, right. Or where is it documented elsewhere? Actually, *in this case*, it doesn't make it look much prettier as you only get rid of one backslash... ;-)

Comment: yeah, it is specific to Vim and it makes it easier to use regex elements like `( ) | {}` free of escaping.. the `\V` is opposite.. see `:h \v` for more info

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the end match marker:

```
%s/\n\ze\D/\t/
```

Another way to do it is to using negative lookahead:

```
%s/\n\d\@!/\t/
```

They are not exactly equivalent, the second will also replace the last newline in a file.

Comment: Thanks Sato, both worked, but @Kusalananda replied first....

Answer (score -2):

I hope this will help you

```
:%s#\n.\D#\t#g
```

Comment: This has the feature that it gobbles up *two* characters, and it also matches digits directly after newlines, which was not wanted. Please test your answers.